# How to implement sql databases in discord.py bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm new to python and was trying to create a python bot, I wanted a optimized way to modify and access my bot configs per server. I had 2 ideas on how/when to fetch configs from the database for optimization.

1. this is what you would normally do - just fetch data variables(fetch a variable at a time) for each command, this would keep the bot simple and minimize unused recources.
2. In this one, whenever the user uses a command for the first time, it fetches the entire config table and stores it in a `loaded` dict from which you can access the config from. you can also update the config in the dict and every 30m-1hr it will log the values in the table and empty the dict. The benefit of this one is less sql calls but potentially less scalability because of unused objects in the dict.

Can someone help me decide which one is better, i dont know normally how you would make discord bots or the convention.

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach is called **caching the data**. You're basically creating a cached database in your application (the dictionary) and save a bunch of usually necessary data to access them quickly. It is what every (almost every) major service (like Steam) does in order to minimize the main database calls.
I think this is the better practice however it has its drawbacks.

**First**, from time to time, you have to compare the cached data with what you have in the original database because your bot will not have a single user and while the cached data is available to one user, another user might alter the data in the original database.

**Second**, it is harder to implement than the first approach. You need to determine which data to store, which data to update rapidly and also you need to implement an alarm system for the users to update their cache whenever the main data is altered in the database.
If I were you and I just wanted to mess around with bots, I would go with just fetching the data each time from the database. It's easier and it is good enough for most applications.